# how to convert xcode 4.6 in xcode 5 in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed an application in xcode 4.6, now I have to change it to xcode 5. I tried many solutions but my UI is disturbing while converting in xcode5. Is there any way to convert xcode 4.6 to xcode 5????

Comment: you would be seeing issues from changing to the iOS 7 SDK (most likely related to status bar / extended content edges). the solution is to go through them one at a time, and fix each issue. there isn't a switch to make it Xcode 5 compatible

Comment: Is the goal of using multiple question marks to increase priority or accuracy of the answer?